# Symfony2 - Controller as a Service - Routing via annotations

Tags: symfony, service, controller, routes, annotations

I am experimenting with creating controllers as services as shown at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html.  I’ve followed this example and everything works fine when I have the route set in app/config/routing.yml.  However when I try and set the route via annotations I get an error

My routing.yml file looks like this:

```
#hello:
#    path:     /hello/{name}
#    defaults: { _controller: app.hello_controller:indexAction }

hello:
resource: "@EventBundle/Controller/HelloController.php"
type:     annotation
```

My controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Me\EventBundle\Controller;

//use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

//class HelloController extends Controller
class HelloController
{

private $templating;

public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
{
    $this->templating = $templating;
}

/**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello")
 *
 */
public function indexAction($name)
{
    return $this->templating->renderResponse(
    'EventBundle:Default:test.html.twig',
    array('name' => $name)
);
}
}
```

As I say if I just use routing.yml and not the annotations the page renders correctly. However using annotations I get the error:

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Me\EventBundle\Controller\HelloController::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface, none given, called in /Library/WebServer/Documents/symfony-project/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2176 and defined

EDIT - as requested in comments:

service.yml looks like:

```
services:
app.hello_controller:
    class: Me\EventBundle\Controller\HelloController
    arguments: ['@templating']
```

Comment: Try adding the ID of the `controller (service)` to your annotation mapping. `@Route("/example", service="my_service_id")`

Comment: can you post your services.yml file

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#controller-as-service

Comment: @SeifSayed I have posted services.yml now.

Comment: @Artamiel is the ID app.hello_controller as per the service.yml now included?

Comment: @Cerad so for example  @Route(service="app.hello_controller")?

Comment: Yes, that is the ID of your service.

Comment: try to drop the ' ' from, also try clearing your cache

Comment: Having quotes or not, the arguments are resolved just fine. I've added the correct syntax to fix this issue in my first comment, and @Cerad included the right link to the documentation as well. It's simple as that.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It's late here but I'll try the fix in the morning and report back

Comment: great thanks guys. Adding  @Route(service="app.hello_controller") just above my class name fixes things

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer with thanks especially to @Artamiel and @Cerad was to add @Route(service="app.hello_controller") just above my class name, so it now looks like:

```
/**
* @Route(service="app.hello_controller")
*/
class HelloController
{

private $templating;

public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
{
    $this->templating = $templating;
}
..........etc
```